# Spark jobServer doesn't start

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, spark-jobserver

I've just got a weird problem when I attempt to instantiate the Spark Jobserver.

It seems it's looking at a wrong directory. Does anybody know something about this?. Maybe I am missing something but the directory **/usr/share/dse/bin/dse** doesnt't exist at all!.

```
-bash-4.2$ dse spark-jobserver start
/usr/share/dse/spark/spark-jobserver/server_start.sh: line 82: /usr/share/dse/bin/dse: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$


DSE 4.8.2,
OS: Centos 7
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug and is being fixed in the next version of DSE (you will see DSP-7052 in the release notes).

I believe you have a package install and that your `dse` binary is in `/usr/bin`. Please change line 82 in `server_start.sh` to `/usr/bin/dse` for now. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

**UPDATE:**
This is fixed in the latest version of DSE

Comment: Thank you for the details. I got the server working now! Cheers